# Framer/Coffeescript: How can I prevent going backwards on a page component?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, framerjs

I guess this is a Framer specific question. I have a page component and I only want you to be able to swipe forwards and not backwards. What's the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the page after it changes.

```
page.onChange "currentPage", ->
    page.previousPage.destroy() 

    page.currentPage.animate 
        backgroundColor: "#FFF"
        options:
            time: 0.5
```